# Check generated fields, then submit in PHP

Tags: php, input

I have a PHP script dat generates lines where you put information in. The user can set the amount of lines he wants.

When a field is not filled in, the field becomes green (works). When everything is filled in, the rows of information get send to the DB.

Problem:
If I have 2 rows and the first row is filled in correctly and the second row isn't, the first line get send to the database because I programmed per row do this.

Code:

```
for($x=0;$x<$i;$x++){
  if (
    empty($_POST["datum".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["campus_id".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["lesuur".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["klasgroep".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["leerkracht".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["lokaal".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["vervanger".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["vervanglokaal".$x])||
    empty($_POST["opmerking".$x])
    )
  {
    echo "";
  } else {

    processForm($x);
    $_SESSION['opgeslagen']=1;
    header('Refresh: 0;url=invoer.php');
  }
}
```

What I want to do is run my for loop, when everything in every row is filled in, THEN do the processform with the parameter in it but I can't make it work...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use two loops to check… first do the check, then process if necessary?

Comment: `header('Refresh: 0;url=invoer.php');`, In a loop ? Seriously?

Comment: the page refreshes after everything (per row) is send to the database, I work with a a session to then show "Everything is sent to the database" ...

Comment: @Eselko, I think, refresh should be done only once, otherwise you would loose your `POST` data. That's why only first row is processing correctly.

Comment: The system works when I fill in 10 or even more rows correctly & sure I want to use the refresher once but it can only be done if the if-statement gives a false (empty fields?->no->false) and there I am, stuck in the for-loop...

Comment: Use something like a `flag` variable inside loop and make it false in the `if` part. Then after loop, if flag is set to true i.e. there is no empty record, then do the processing and your refresh. Atleast I'd try with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned before, simply use one loop to check everything, then another to process everything if the checks were all successful.

```
$failure = false;
for($x=0;$x<$i;$x++){
  if (
    empty($_POST["datum".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["campus_id".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["lesuur".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["klasgroep".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["leerkracht".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["lokaal".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["vervanger".$x]) ||
    empty($_POST["vervanglokaal".$x])||
    empty($_POST["opmerking".$x])
    )
  {
    $failure = true;
  }
}

if(!$failure) {
  for($x=0;$x<$i;$x++){
    processForm($x);
  }
  $_SESSION['opgeslagen']=1;
  header('Refresh: 0;url=invoer.php');
}
```

Comment: Seems to work a little, when I set 5 rows and fill them all in and submit, the page doesn't refresh. It does when rows =<2... Any idea?

Comment: Moved the header and session out of the loop, should fix the problem. If you want it to always refresh even when it fails, simply move the header function below the if block

Comment: I've changed it but some problem. If I have 1 or 2 rows it empties the information but with 5 rows the information stays but is still send through...

Comment: Or you can try to post all the data in `processForm()` function at once, in the form of array, then it should solve the "abnormal behaviour" of your code.

Comment: Never mind, fixed it by putting 'ob_start();' at the start and 'ob_end_flush();' at the end of the code! Thanks